# SQL Server Query Formulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query for my database and I'm having some serious trouble getting it to where it needs to be.

What I need it to do:

Among listing other things, It needs to check through an HoursWorked Table and find out which employees worked on April and list them. Then it needs list the number of hours those employees worked (COUNT)

I'll show you what I put together which isn't complete as it's late and I'm running out of ideas:

```
SELECT
    (cl.CommonName + '(' + cl.LegalName + ')') AS ClientName,
    p.ProjectName,
    (e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName) AS EmpName, 
    SUM(wh.HoursWorked) AS Hours,
    br.Rate,'$'+FORMAT((Rate * SUM(HoursWorked)), '#,0.00') TotalCharges,  
    (con.LastName + ', ' + con.FirstName + ' - ' + con.AddrLine1 + ' ' + con.AddrLine2) AS Contact
FROM
    Clients cl,
    Projects p,
    Employees e,
    WorkHours wh,
    BillingRates br,
    Contacts con,
    Contracts cont
WHERE
    cl.ClientID = cont.ClientID
    AND cont.ContractID = p.ContractID
    AND e.Level = br.Level
    AND e.TitleID = br.TitleID
    AND e.EmpId = wh.EmpId
    AND EXISTS 
    ( SELECT * FROM WorkHours
        WHERE WH_Month = 4 )
GROUP BY
    cl.CommonName,
    cl.LegalName
ORDER BY
    ClientName,
    p.ProjectName,
    EmpName
```

This is my schema:

[image: My Schema]

Result should include:

- Client Name
- Contract Name(s)
- Project(s) Employees who logged hours to a project from the first day of the current month until the last    day of the current month
- Total number of hours logged for each employee during the month
- Employee rate
- Total Charges per employee (i.e. employee rate x employee hours worked)
- Billing contact(s) - [name, address] for each contract

Comment: If it's about employees and their hours, why are you also including clients into the query? Or did you mean hours per employee & client?

Comment: First, try not to use old-style-joins: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.  For example: there's no `WHERE` clause for Contacts in your query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: ClientName is one of the required output.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I need to figure look at how to join them harder then. I've never really used an ANSI Join for anything over 2 tables yet. One of the stipulations for the query is it has to encompass everything in a single query

Comment: Very well, what would the required output look like? At first I thought it would be as simple as two columns: `EmployeeName` and `Hours` where `EmployeeName` would contain unique employee names. How would the output look with client names? Could you illustrate it in your post?

Comment: It really helps to create a SQLFiddle and provide a required resultset with the data in the fiddle.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to get it set up in SQL Fiddle. I've never used it before and it looks like just getting the schema in in almost at the character limit. Either way, I;m going to crash for tonight. Ill check back in on this tomorrow morning. Thanks for all the help so far everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out this:

```
AND EXISTS 
( SELECT * FROM WorkHours
    WHERE WH_Month = 4 )
```

With this:

```
WHERE wh.WH_Month = 4
```

What you have in your query says "If there is any record in the table with month=4, give me this record in my results, regardless of what month it is tied to".  There is nothing tying the "current" result to the month, so it will return every record.

Edit: I'm also in support of replacing old-school comma joins for current methods, and in your schema I don't see a lot of foreign key relationships or anything relating the tables you are selecting...for instance, how do you know what Client a given Project/Contract is for?  Just food for thought.